# Types of Concurrent processes

Tags: process, operating-system, multiprocessing, processor, concurrent-programming

> "Processes may be described as physically concurrent and logically
>   concurrent processes, the distinction between them is analogous to
>   that between real and virtual processors"

what does that mean?

What is the difference between physically concurrent and logically concurrent processes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the difference between physically concurrent and logically
>   concurrent processes?

Suppose if you've a single core processor, and suppose if you have multithreading in your code, it'll show as if it is running in parallel in multiple different processors; but, in reality it utilises the single processor, where quantum of time is allotted to each threads in round-robin manner. In this case, the processes(OR threads) seem to be running in parallel concurrently, but, in reality, there is context switch many-a-times between the processes(threads) to simulate as if they are running simultaneously.

Whereas, had you been having multiple cores in your processor(or multiple processors), your multithreaded code would have executed in parallel on different cores(or processors, if there) concurrently! In this case, the processes are running in parallel concurrently.

I hope it clears your doubt! Feel free to ask in case of further queries.

Comment: You missed a point - a single core can support multiple threads simultaneously.

Comment: @babon - Would you like to describe in detail about what I missed here in my answer?

Comment: A thread is a stream of instructions. Cores supporting multiple threads can process multiple threads simultaneously. You may check this link: http://superuser.com/questions/700430/what-does-2-core-4-threads-mean-in-cpu

Comment: @babon - I didn't want to talk about Intel's hyperthreading here. Actually, in reality `For each processor core that is physically present, the operating system addresses two virtual (logical) cores and shares the workload between them when possible.` So, finally, it again boils down to logical cores which I don't want to introduce here.

Comment: Fine. BTW, it's not about Intel's hyperthreading. It's about SMT, just that Intel's implementation is named HT.

Comment: @babon - Yeah, same. Whatever, I don't want to introduce SMT too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is very much explanatory.